# How to translate webpage into any language the user selects from a select menu

Tags: jquery, google-translate

I have a simple webpage with just 1 sentence of text in a div and a title tag.  I think that I am pretty close to getting the div translated into another language.  The language obviously starts out with English.  How can I use Google translate to translate the words in my div tag and also my title tag.  So far, I have wrote the code below which I think should translate the div, but it looks like there is a Javascript error that I can't figure out.  I'm also wondering if this is a free service provided by Google, or if I need to sign up and pay for this service through an api of some sort.

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: "en" }, "trans");
};

$(function () {
    $.getScript("//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>I want this title to be translated</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <p>I want this text to be translated into the language the user selects from the menu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="trans"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works. It's just blocked by the security restrictions in place on SO snippets. If you run it in a less restrictive sandbox, such as jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ps9L08e/, or your own site, it will work correctly.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that translates the entire page.  I'm not sure why, but this only seems to work in the Google Chrome browser.  https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/0stLrpqg/

Comment: Is the problem solved?